# sqlldr not recognizing new line/row

Tags: oracle, import, sqlplus

Our organization switched to a new tool and now our text files are generated with only a trailing CR instead of a CR & LF.  Now sqlldr thinks all of the data in the file is 1 row.  How can I fix this?

Here is our typical setup:

```
    ------------------------------
    -- CREATE THE CONTROL FILE:
    ------------------------------
    SET HEADING OFF PAGES 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF TERM OFF;
    SPOOL &&client-ws.ctl

    SELECT  'load data ' || CHR (10) || 
            'infile * ' || CHR (10) || 
            'TRUNCATE ' || CHR (10) || 
            'into table TMP_ID_LIST' || CHR (10) || 
            'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''    '' ' || CHR (10) || 
            '( ' || CHR (10) || 
            'ID )' FROM DUAL;

    SPOOL OFF;

    ------------------------------
    -- LOAD FROM FILE INTO TABLE:
    ------------------------------
    HOST sqlldr control=&&client-ws.ctl  data=&&input_file log=&&client-ld.log userid=&&userid/&&password@&&db silent=header direct=y
```

In the paricular case i'm trying to solve, it is only 1 column.  Example data:

```
    b55369fd-3919-4baf-808c-ceacfe5afaac
    b8c54bf7-7fba-4569-bd75-54f7fc9d5210
    75c48437-8acf-4c34-ab76-a0d5c282d81f
    d62272fe-5132-42ec-aea8-f084151168d4
```

Halp pweez :D - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to have your tool generate the output in the proper format.

If that is not possible, just use `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` on the file before processing, depending on the direction you need. Both utilites are provided as part of the `dos2unix` package that can be installed from the default Linux repositories, or downloaded seperately.

Other alternatives involve `perl`, `sed` or `tr`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos

unix2dos:

> ```
> perl -i -p -e 's|[\r\n]+|\r\n|g' file
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> sed -i -e 's/\r*$/\r/' file
> ```

dos2unix:

> ```
> tr -d '\r' < file > file2 # For ASCII and other files which do not contain multibyte characters (Not utf-8 safe).
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> perl -i -p -e 's/\r//g' file
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> sed -i -e 's/\r//g' file
> ```

Comment: I like where your mind is on this but it's a windows box that I cannot install these tools on (locked down).  Was hoping for a way to handle with the control file.  We did figure out the issue occurs when the user creates the CSV from excel.  May be something we can configure there.  Thank you!

Comment: @flashsplat You can do with powershell  in windows.Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248726/how-can-i-insert-a-carriage-return-linefeed-every-x-characters-with-notepad

Comment: @Sam Ok, i can look into that a little.  The given solution there is based on a set length.  While they are the same for this example they generally vary.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as the problem is with the file and not sqlldr.  Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I wanted to post how we fixed this.  Turned out, the users were saving the CSV from excel as **Macintosh CSV**.  Yes.  They are noobs.  Once we flogged them for this behavior, we had no more issues.

Thanks!